# CDK secretsmanager.Secret secretName is a token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I cannot seem to access a CDK secretsmanager.Secret secretName to use within an Aspect, here's how I'm defining the Secret:

```
new secretsmanager.Secret(this, 'MySecret', {
  secretName: 'my-secret-name'
})
```

However, inside the Aspect, when I attempt to access the secretName:

```
export default class NameCheckAspect implements cdk.IAspect {
  visit(node: IConstruct): void {
    if (node instanceof secretsmanager.Secret) {
      console.log(node.secretName)
    }
  }
}
```

I expected that to log 'my-secret-name', however, it logs: '${Token[Fn::Join.248]}'. So I then tried to resolve the Token using the construct's stack:

```
export default class NameCheckAspect implements cdk.IAspect {
  visit(node: IConstruct): void {
    if (node instanceof secretsmanager.Secret) {
      console.log(cdk.Stack.of(node).resolve(node.secretName))
    }
  }
}
```

But that resolves to a CloudFormation Fn::Join:

```
{
  'Fn::Join': [
    '-',
    [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  ]
}
```

Why does it do this and not just give me back the string secretName I set? Does anyone know if there is a sane way to get the secretName back **without** needing to resort to escape hatches?

Comment: You can use the token just like you would the complete string, as long as you don't do any string operations on it. It will be resolved during deployment.

Comment: I am writing an Aspect which validates that the format of the specified name for the secret adheres to company policy, so I need to get the actual string name, not the unresolved token. This Aspect will, of course, execute before deployment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try get name trough `cfnProperties`:

```js
const secret = node.defaultChild as secretsmanager.CfnSecret;
const secretName = secret.cfnProperties.SecretName as string | undefined;
```

It should be a resolved name.

Comment: Hey @Lasek, I was attempting to do this "without needing to resort to escape hatches", however, I think that's the only way that this can be done, so I have _had_ to take that approach

Comment: @user3067870 thats right, its not only that secretname is optional but token helps CF in managing resources deps.